# Can I install .net framework 3.5 on windows 7 32bit

Tags: .net, vb.net

I uninstall .net framework 4.5 from my windows 7 32 bit computer.
but I need to use .net framework 3.5 for new project.

Where can I get .net framework 3.5 SP1 for windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: It's built into Windows 7. Just go into system features and make sure that .NET Framework is turned on.

Comment: I turned on .net framework 3.5 in system features after this problem happen. But I don't see .net framework 3.5 in uninstall program list and also can't see in command prompt

Comment: You won't see it in the uninstall program list *because* it's built in. You won't see e.g. IIS in the uninstall program list for exactly the same reason. I don't know what you mean by the command prompt.

Comment: If it is built in, it not diplay in uninstall program list? I didn't know it. so I worried about not having .net framework on my pc.             in command prompt I write as follow..wmic product where "name like 'Microsoft .NET Framework%'" get name,version    , when .net framework 4.5 it display as 4.5

Comment: Yes, again that's dealing with separately installed items. Just open an explorer window and look in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net`. You should see directories for v2.0.50727, v3.0 and v3.5 if 3.5 is installed.

Comment: If so, I don't need to install 3.5 again even it is not display in installed program list?

Answer (score 8):

The .NET framework is backwards compatible. You can program and compile against 3.5 with 4.5 installed.

See [How to: Target a Version of the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In case you have uninstalled or do not have .NET framework 4.5/4 or 3.5 installed on your PC and want to install 3.5 specifically, here is the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21)

Comment: But if you look at the system requirements, you'll see that the highest supported client OS is Vista.

Comment: my bad. Windows 7 comes with .NET framework 3.5 SP1 by default. The only change required is to select the correct framework version in the project properties page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to my computer and click on C drive and then click on Windows.  Scroll down and you will see MicrosoftNET.  Click on it and you see two files.  Select Framework and click.  Scrolldown and you will see v3.5.  Click on it and you will see MicrosoftNetFramework 3.5  Click on it and scrolldown you will see Setup.  It is an application file.  Click on it and you are set.

Pokossy@hotmail.com